# Displaying a large value (Trillion) in a table in decimal form e.g 5.8 trillion

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I need to add a new column to my sharepoint dashboard(created using Jquery). The value is a number which is extremly large and causing my dashboard to become mis figured. I have values in the trillions e.g (565000000000.001) .

I need to dipaly this value in decimal e.g 5.65 trillion. Can someone please point me in the right direction :)

My table code below:

```
       TableRowHtml +="<TR><TD style='text-align: Left'>Curr</TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'>" + Curr[0].toFixed(2) + "</TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'>" + Curr[1].toFixed(2)+ "</TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'><img alt='' src=' IMAGE" + Curr1 + "'></TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'><img alt='' src=' IMAGE" + Curr7 + "'></TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'><img alt='' src='IMAGE" + Curr30 + "'></TD><TD 'style='font-size: 10px'> <div id='div3' style='float: right; width: 75px;  height: 30px; margin-bottom: -20px! important;'></div></TD></TR>";
```

Comment: Note that in your example, it's only half a trillion.

Comment: What kind of number system do you want to use? U.S./U.K? Billion is different in UK and US number systems.. The answers below work if the number is always in the Trillions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide value by a trillion, then round down to 2 decimals.

And in case you can not round to a certain amount of decimals:
Divide value by a trillion/100 (ie 10.0000.000.000), then round, then divide by 100.

In code:

```
(Curr[1] / 1000000000000).toFixed(2)
```

And alternative (gives you 5 instead of 5.00)

```
(Curr[1] / 10000000000).toFixed(0)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing your huge value by 10<sup>12</sup>:

```
TableRowHtml += "<TR><TD style='text-align: left'>Curr</TD>"
    + "<TD style='font-size: 10px'>"
    + (Curr[0] / 1E12).toFixed(2) + " trillions" + "</TD>...";
```

By the way, I'm never sure of the `trillion` designation in English, but shouldn't `565 000 000 000.001` be `0.565` trillion?